# How to determine $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n^4-n^2+1}$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to determine if the series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n^4-n^2+1}$$
is convergent or divergent? Which test should I use?

Comment: Use LCT. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(n^2+1)^2}{(n^6+1)}\leq 2+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n^4+2n^2+1}{n^6} = -2+\zeta(2)+2\zeta(4)+\zeta(6)\approx 2.8269236.$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINTS:**

Note that we have

$$n^2+1\le2n^2$$

and

$$n^4-n^2+1\ge \frac12n^4$$

for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Why $n^2+1<n^2$?

Comment: @GuachoPerez That was a typo.  I've edited.

Comment: @Dr.MV Then there should be equality too in first one, for n=1.

Comment: @Dr.MV no problem, just making sure!

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thanks;  edited

Answer (score 0):

You can also use limit comparison test by comparing its terms with terms of the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$.